# How to explicitly express a recursion function

Tags: probability, functions, recurrence-relations

Let $p_{x}(x)$ be a probability mass function of a random variable X defined on the positive integers which satisfies the recursive relation:

$$p_{x}(x+1) = \frac{\theta}{x + 1}p_{x}(x)$$
Where $\theta > 0$ and $p_{x}(1)$ is fixed

Determine explicitly $p_{x}$ as a function of $x$ and $\theta$ only. The function found should not depend on $p_{x}(1)$.

I am genuinely at my wits end here. I calculated $p_{x}$ for $x = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ and tried playing around with algebra and substitution to no avail. I have like 3 sheets of paper full of fruitless attempts. I've never done anything like this before and could really use a nudge in the right direction. Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is a difference equation. Do you know what is the value $p_x(0)$?

Comment: I do not. All I know is that $\theta > 0$ and that $p_x(1)$ is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

Write $p_x(1) = \lambda$ for now.  We don't know what $\lambda$ is but we will solve for it later.

[Step 1] Now write down $p_x(2), p_x(3),$ etc using the recurrence.  Can you find a formula for $p_x(n)$ in terms of only $n, \theta$ and $\lambda$?

[Step 2] Assuming you can do Step 1, there seems to be two parameters, $\theta$ and $\lambda$.  $\theta$ is a given, so you need to find out what $\lambda$ is.  Now this is a probability distribution, and every $p_x(n)=$ the probability $Prob(X=n)$.  There is a very basic constraint on probabilities $p_x(n): n=1, 2, \dots$ that help you solve for $\lambda$.

Can you finish from here or do you need another hint?

Comment: $p_{x}(1) = \lambda$   
$p_{x}(2) = \frac{\theta}{2}\lambda$   
$p_{x}(3) = \frac{\theta}{2}p_{x}(2) = \frac{\theta}{2}\frac{\theta}{3}\lambda =\frac{\theta^2}{6}$  

My guess for the formula is $p_{x}(n) = \frac{\theta^{n-1}}{n!}\lambda$  Now I have to use properties of probability mass functions to solve for lambda.

Comment: I used the property  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda\frac{\theta^{n-1}}{n!} = 1 $ and ended up with $\lambda = \frac{1}{\theta e^{\theta}}$. Is that right?

Comment: It's late night here in Boston and I dont trust my own algebra... :)   but I thought: shouldnt it be $\lambda = \theta / e^\theta$ instead?  Anyway, regardless of whether you're right or I'm right, you're definitely on the right track, so just substitute in the correct $\lambda$ and you have what the question is asking for, i.e. $p_x(x)$ as a function of $x$ and $\theta$ only (and does not involve $p_x(1))$.

Comment: Yeah I made a tiny mistake in my algebra, your $\lambda$ is correct. Thank you for the assistance.